# ElasticSearch - How to Update with Api Update

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-6

I need help to use Api Update in elasticsearch, the problem is what I have when I want to update this level further inside the structure, for example:

```
{
"mainLevel": [
    {   "idmainLevel": 1,
        "name": "maxi",
        "SecundaryLevel": [
            {
                "idSecundaryLevel": 25,
                "title": "Bachelor"
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

In this case the update would like to do it in "SecondaryLevel" but for a certain "MainLevel", I leave my index below.

```
# Index an animal
POST test_object/animales/1
  {
"name": "test_object",
"cats": [
  {
  "id_cat": 1,
  "name": "Irida",
  "breed": "European Shorthair"
},
{
  "id_cat": 2,
  "name": "Nino",
  "breed": "Aegean",
  "toys": [
      {
        "id_toy": 1,
        "colors": 1,
        "name": "pelotita"
      }
  ]
}
],
"dogs": [
{
  "id_dog": 1,
  "name": "Irida",
  "breed": "European Shorthair"
}
]
}
```

My Update:

```
POST test_object/animales/1/_update
{
    "script": {
       "source": "ctx._source.toys.add(params.val)",
       "lang": "painless",
       "params": {
           "val": {
               "id_toy": 2,
               "colors": 77,
               "name": "cricket"
           }
       }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

In the inserted object, there's no toy attribute in the object with Id 1 on first level. Your update probably causes a null pointer exception.

If I understand you correctly, you want to append to the toys list (if it exists in the object). For this, you can use an if condition to see if the 'toys' field exists ([see answer on elastic forum](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-check-a-doc-field-exist-while-creating-scripted-field-using-painless/74355)), before doing an 'add' operation on the list to avoid the null pointer exception.

For a more systematic approch, I've always found it helpful to start from a very ... VERY simple prototype in painless. I'd recommend the same to you. Try appending to an object only containing a list, and then add the if condition, and then the rest.

Comment: Yes, in the normal way it works well for me, but when I want to update an object that in turn belongs to another object, it is where I cannot. I included "id" to each of the objects but I still have the same problem.

Comment: Have you updated the question to reflect this issue? :)